# Calculating Sum if Cell in same row is String

Tags: google-sheets, sum

So I am in Google Sheets and need to be able to add up all the values in part of a column, as long as the cell first cell in the same row is consistent.
Example:

[image: Spreadsheet image]

If you take a look at the image, I have calculated the sum of 'record_count' for all the cells where 'Name' = 'Booker' - it's about 80 rows. I did this by manually defining the range. I need to be able to use a formula that will sum every cell in 'record_count' as long as the 'Name' (column B) is consistent. Once 'Name' changes, I need the formula to start summing up every cell where 'Name' = a different name.

I will be pasting this data from the output of a monthly SQL query, and don't want to have to keep manually defining ranges. I want it to be dynamic. If I got down past row 80 the Name changes to 'Softhouse' and I want to be able sum every cell in 'record_count' where 'Name' = 'Softhouse'.

The formula I currently have in J3 is `=IF(C3=C4,SUM(D$3:D$80),null)` This only works for the first use, then gradually decreases if I drag it down.

Any help at all would be most appreciated. Also, I can provide as much extra info as needed.

Comment: This sounds like you need a [Pivot table](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function sumif: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496

For your case,try this function below,just change 99 to big enough for your real data: `J3=SUMIFS(D$3:D$99, B$3:B$99, CONCATENATE("=",B3))`

Here is a sample:

[image: a sumif sample]

Comment: Okay, this answer.... Amazing. The ear to ear grin I got after I saw '57186' in that cell after simply pasting the sumif function you gave me.... thank you. I was beginning mess around with 'sum if' before I posted here. Thank you

Comment: This is great. Can you elaborate on the 'CONCATENATE' and "=", please? I am trying to do a similar function where instead of calculating the sum of every 'Name's' record count, I am trying to count the number of times column 'Name has the string 'company name'. I think a 'count' is in order.

Comment: correction: countif ...    `=COUNTIF(L$3:L$999,  CONCATENATE("=",L4))`

Answer (score 2):

`QUERY` will give you a summary:

```
=QUERY(A:I,"Select A,sum(D) group by A",2)
```

The correct implementation of `IF` is

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(C3=C$3:C$80,D$3:D$80)))
```

Comment: Also worked! Will have to look more into the `arrayformula` function. Thank you!